# magento invoice exists but has no id

Tags: php, magento, invoice

I made a custom module with observer:  and everything works fine except the invoice ID. The invoice id remains empty. I tried the following code:

```
$event = $observer->getEvent();
$invoice = $event->getInvoice();
$order = $invoice->getOrder();

Mage::log($invoice->getId(), null, "test.txt");
Mage::log($invoice->getEntityId(), null, "test.txt");
Mage::log($invoice->getData("entity_id"), null, "test.txt");
```

It keeps printing an empty string for the invoice ID.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: What event are you observing?

Comment: <sales_order_invoice_save_after>

Comment: I have no idea. At a first glance I conclude that it should work. Try logging `$invoice->getData()` and see what you get there.

Comment: Problem solved, just like that, nothing changed, and it works

Comment: Yeah...I know this kind of problems. It's called 'BugFoot'. You think you saw it but you didn't :).